# Node.js + Ember.js Login System

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ember.js, authentication

I have a server running node.js and my client-side is in ember.js.

```
I'm trying to implement a login system but there is not much on the interner about these two tools working together. I've got a simple authentication system
```

**But what I need to do is the $_SESSION part like in php**.

I can login and get my information right away but I don't know how to remain logged in to forbid/allow to go trough certain pages. I need some cookies or something but not quite seeing how I'm going to do this with these two tools.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You just need access to cookies via node? https://github.com/expressjs/cookies

Comment: but my problem is on the ember.js side to keep the user logged in

Answer (score 0):

Here are two examples of handling sessions/authentication and login in ember
https://github.com/embercasts/authentication-part-1

https://github.com/embercasts/authentication-part-2

here is a ember-addon
https://github.com/Vestorly/torii

you can store the session token in a cookie, so that when the page is closed the application can retrieve it.

you can send the session token to your nodejs api to authorize the user to whatever resources you are using